# Can I block inbound traffic from a certain ISP

Tags: security, firewall, ddos

#### The problem

My server keeps getting DDoS attacks from IP's belonging to Ecatel in The Netherlands. I wrote them a month ago and still haven't heard anything, and keep blocking individual IP addresses whenever my server slows to a crawl isn't a prudent solution.

#### Server info

I'm running an EC-2 micro on AWS, so if it's possible to do something clever with the AWS security groups, that might be the best solution.

I'm not really sure what options I have here, but I assume I can block traffic from a certain ISP. Is that possible?

```
inetnum:        *ip-from* - *ip-to*
netname:        NL-ECATEL
descr:          *address*
country:        NL
admin-c:        EL25-RIPE
tech-c:         EL25-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         ECATEL-MNT
mnt-lower:      ECATEL-MNT
mnt-routes:     ECATEL-MNT
changed:         20080621
source:         RIPE

role:           Ecatel LTD
address:        *address*
address:        *address*
address:        Netherlands
abuse-mailbox:  
remarks:        ----------------------------------------------------
remarks:        ECATEL LTD
remarks:        Dedicated and Co-location hosting services
remarks:        ----------------------------------------------------
remarks:        for abuse complaints : 
remarks:        for any other questions : 
remarks:        ----------------------------------------------------
e-mail:         
admin-c:        EL25-RIPE
tech-c:         EL25-RIPE
nic-hdl:        EL25-RIPE
mnt-by:         ECATEL-MNT
changed:        20130201
source:         RIPE

route:          89.248.172.0/23
descr:          AS29073, Route object
origin:         AS29073
mnt-by:         ECATEL-MNT
changed:        20071119
source:         RIPE
```

Comment: You can block the entire 89.248.172.0/23 range: `iptables -A INPUT  -s 89.248.172.0/23 -j DROP`. The packets will still reach your server and use bandwidth, but they will not reach your services.

Comment: If you can afford it, it's maybe time to look for anti DDOS solution subscription rather than block an entire ISP (depends on your business).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it doesn't take much at all to tie ip a t1.micro instance - if you want the instance to do anything meaningful, you want to be using a larger instance type.

As for blocking requests - you will not be able to drop traffic using the instance's security groups, as it lets you allow traffic, not drop it. You can run a local iptables firewall on the instance and add the subnet manually.

A better solution altogether is to install and configure [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to automatically add individual IPs that exhibit DDoS-like behaviour to an iptables chain. The whole process is beyond the scope of a ServerFault answer, but check these links for some detail: [(1)](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/fail2ban/) [(2)](https://www.quickhostuk.com/knowledgebase/470/Fail2Ban-to-limit-DDOS-attacks-on-https-webserver.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into fail2ban.

As for the instance, it's being used to run my portfolio website and blog so a micro instance tuned right is just fine for what I need :)